# Сериализация класса, который содержит данные из БД в XML

Tags: c#, xml, oracle

У меня есть класс который обращается к базе Оракл и получает значения таблицы

Как мне потом сериализовать ответ в XML и вывести его в `return`.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public const string OZapros = "SELECT a.name ...";
    private static string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Oracle"].ConnectionString;

    public string Zapros(string wro, string regnum, string kpp, string inn)
    {   
        //List<T> items = new List<T>();

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("reg_number", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = regnum;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("ххх", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = wro;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("ххх", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = kpp;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("ххх", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = inn;

                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = OZapros;
                cmd.BindByName = true;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;

                using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var pp = new List<T>();

                    if (reader.HasRows) 
                    {
                        // выводим названия столбцов
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} \t{1} \t{2} \t{3} \t{4} \t{5} \t{6} \t{7} \t{8} \t{9} \t{10} \t{11}", reader.GetName(0), reader.GetName(1), reader.GetName(2), reader.GetName(3), reader.GetName(4), reader.GetName(5), reader.GetName(6), reader.GetName(7), reader.GetName(8), reader.GetName(9), reader.GetName(10), reader.GetName(11));

                        while (reader.Read()) // построчно считываем данные
                        {
                            var obj = new T();
                            obj.S = reader.GetString(0);
                            obj.S1 = reader.GetString(1);
                            obj.S2 = reader.GetInt32(2);
                            obj.S3 = reader.GetString(3);
                            obj.S4 = reader.GetString(4);
                            obj.S5 = reader.GetDateTime(5);
                            obj.S6 = reader.GetString(6);
                            obj.S7 = reader.GetString(7);
                            obj.S8 = reader.GetString(8);
                            obj.S9 = reader.GetString(9);
                            obj.S10 = reader.GetString(10);
                            obj.S11 = reader.GetString(11);

                            pp.Add(obj);

                        } 

                    }

                  }

             }

        } 
       return ???;  
    }

}
public class T
{

    public string S { get; set; }
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public int S2 { get; set; }
    public string S3 { get; set; }
    public string S4 { get; set; }
    public DateTime S5 { get; set; }
    public string S6 { get; set; }
    public string S7 { get; set; }
    public string S8 { get; set; }
    public string S9 { get; set; }
    public string S10 { get; set; }
    public string S11 { get; set; }
    public string S12 { get; set; }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала помечаете класс атрибутом Serilizable

```
[Serializable]
public class ProgData
{
    public string DataString { get; set; }
}
```

А, дальше всё очень просто:

```
// Создаём объект
ProgData progData = new ProgData { DataString = "Test1" };
// Готовим XmlSerializer для него
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProgData));
// Собственно сериализуем в строку.
using(StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
    return textWriter.ToString();
}
```

Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](http://streletzcoder.ru/xml-serializatsiya-i-deserializatsiya-proizvolnyih-obektov-v-c/) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434534/serialize-an-object-to-string).

Comment: `XmlSerializer` никак не использует атрибут `Serializable`. Этот атрибут нужен для двоичной сериализации (`BinaryFormatter`)